# How can object keys be typed to match a given pattern with unlimited combinations?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to make sure an object only has keys that follow a pattern. That pattern i: "{integer}a+{integer}c". It would look like:

```
{
    "2a+1c": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that any new key added to this object follows this pattern, without laying out all possible keys (as it is not feasible)?

To maybe shed some light to what I'm thinking about, here is how you can make sure that an object only has keys that belong to an enum:

```
type ObjectWithEnumedKeys = {
  [key in TheEnum]?: number;
}
```

I'm not looking for a solution that uses logic (methods in a class, or a closure) to control this.

Comment: Not regular expressions, no, but you can use [template string types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)! (Or just regular string unions)

Comment: If I understood correctly, I would have to create types for all possible keys. Right? That does not suite the case here because what I need is `Xa+Yc`, where `X` and `Y` are numbers

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question to clarify that :)

Comment: Note that "Yes/No" questions, and specifically "Is it possible?" questions are not really a good fit for [so] … or for yourself. These types of questions admit only the two possible answers "Yes" and "No", and neither of those answers is actually particularly helpful. "No" just tells you it is impossible, but doesn't actually solve your problem, and "Yes" just tells you it *is* possible, but still doesn't tell you how to actually solve your problem. (See this meta question on the Software Engineering sister site: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/1352)

Comment: When you initialise a regular expression e.g. by doing `/myregex/g` then this line is not the regular expression it's just a shortcut to create a regular expression instance which its internal workings are encapsulated and possibly vary between different JS engine implementations. How you you possible expect TypeScript to be able to do what you want it when it doesn't even know what JS engine will end up executing the code. You can't say "this parameter is this this object type but only if I constructed that object with this specific object constructor parameter" it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @apokryfos: How is this different from literally any other type? TypeScript doesn't know how each engine implements booleans, strings, numbers, objects, arrays, sets, functions, maps, exceptions, etc. either. And in fact, engines differ greatly in e.g. their implementation of numbers (some use tags, some don't, some have separate types internally for int32s and int53s, some don't) or strings (some use a rope data structure internally instead of a string). By that argument, we should just forget about TypeScript altogether.

Comment: @JörgWMittag the point remains valid. You can't tell typescript to validate a type based on how its constructor was called because what happens with the constructor arguments is implementation detail.

Comment: @ppicom "*what I need is `Xa+Yc`, where `X` and `Y` are numbers*" - that doesn't look like a regex. Do you mean `X` and `Y` can be any number? Then the template literal type `\`${number}a+${number}c\`` would actually do what you need.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks a lot for taking the time and energy necessary for this kind of constructive criticism. I will come up with a different way of asking the question so that it remains clearer for any potential reader/responder. In the meantime, as I'm sure you'll understand, I wont accept your "no" answer; as when I change the question such answer won't really fit :)

Comment: @apokryfos I'm afraid my knowledge about regular expressions, as well as the details of the implementation of JS across different platforms, it's as deep as a glass of water. I apologise for my ignorance. Maybe would you be so kind to point me towards a few references with regard to this matter? I'd love to read some about it :)

Comment: Ok now that you edited the question it's a lot clearer what you need, basically you need a string key to match a given regular expression which was a suggestion for TS to support in [this case](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) and is currently still under discussion in [this case](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160). I was initially confused because  there was a question I was reading earlier which I thought was similar but that one was asking for a type that matches a regex with a flag so may have been confused there. Apologies for that.

Comment: Cool! thanks for the response @apokryfos. I understand that the first version of the question was not all that clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.4 [introduced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) the usage of [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) in index signatures. While they currently allow any number, not just integers, in the interpolations, it's not exactly what you asked for, but comes very close:

```
type TheEnum = `${number}a+${number}c`;
type ObjectWithEnumedKeys = {
  [key in TheEnum]?: number;
}


const x: ObjectWithEnumedKeys = {
  "2a+1c": 3, // works as expected
  "5.5a+3.1c": 8.6, // accepted as well, hm
  "error": undefined, // complains that "property 'error' does not exist in type 'ObjectWithEnumedKeys'", as expected
}
```

<sup>([Demo in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAogOwK4FsoF4oAMAkA3mugEYQBOAvgIYDURJ51AxrgNwBQokUA8qQBWEFsADqAS2BwUGCABMA0hBABnbFEKcoUANoBrFVAnJYCWegC6AfgBcUJpS5VOnFgHtkq4FAAe9gWFRSWkLBWU1DS0dACIAVnoAZhYY+wBGABptKHiAOgS6RNy0lPsAJiydTiogA))</sup>

[Regex-validated string types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) that would let you properly specify integer coefficients are still under discussion.

Comment: the example is really appreciated. I was having a little of a hard time understanding the documentation. I'll mark your answer as correct given that this illustrates perfectly the reason why it's not quite possible to do what I was asking :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to type an object in a way that its keys can only be strings that match a given Regex?

No.

Comment: As I mentioned, given that I've changed the question following your advice I can no longer accept this answer :)